# Android Java with running AsyncTask and loop

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask

I have problems with `AsyncTask` in android programming. I am trying to load weather json file from `OpenWeatherMap` APT in a background thread which is `AsyncTask`.

I have a button in `activity_main.xml` will invoke the "findWeather" function. And `DownloadTask` method will download result file using url. 
However, when I click the button, the app crashed and I got the error showing in the last pic.

I'm really new to android, I think there are might be a problem with the while loop in DownloadTask class but I'm not sure about it...

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   EditText cityName;
   TextView resultTextView;

   public void findWeather(View view) {

       Log.i("cityName", cityName.getText().toString());

       InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)               
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cityName.getWindowToken(), 0);

try {
    String encodedCityName =        
URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

     DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName+"&apiid=5e8119137ab2c795f32cbbc4b046c57f");
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       cityName = findViewById(R.id.cityNameEditText);
       resultTextView =  findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
   }

   public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

           String result = "";
           URL url;
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

           try {
               url = new URL(urls[0]);

               urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

               InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

               InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

               int data = reader.read();

               while (data != -1) {
                   System.out.print("while loop");
                   char current = (char) data;
                   result += current;
                   data = reader.read();
               }

               return result;

           } catch (Exception e) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           }

           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           try {
               String message = "";
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
               String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

               Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

               JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
               for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                   String main = "";
                   String description = "";

                   main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                   description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                   if (main != "" && description != "") {
                       message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";
                   }
               }

               if (message != "") {
                   resultTextView.setText(message);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                               
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.example.wangshuang.weatherapp.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/weather" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cityNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter a city"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Enter a city"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/citybtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:onClick="findWeather"
        android:text="What's the weather"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cityNameEditText"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="118dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/citybtn"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="176dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the error...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please remove Toast from catch section

You are getting exception in `doInBackground` in catch section.
So whenever you want to print the exception message just use

```
e.printstacktrace();
```

You can't use Toast in background thread. It should be used in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a `Toast` in background thread as that is a UI element and requires UI thread to be executed. Hence it can only be shown in postExecute for example in the AsyncTask scenario.

Remove `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`

from the Exception and print the exception using `e.printStackTrace()` and see if you get any error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. It cannot show toast inside the `AsyncTask`. So the simpler way of solving this problem is to remove all toasts from your `AsyncTask` and get the callback of the `AsyncTask` in your `Activity` and then take necessary action based on the callback from your `AsyncTask`.

To prepare a callback mechanism in your `AsyncTask`, you need to declare an `interface` first.

Create an interface, `DownloadListener.java`

```
public interface DownloadListener {
    void onListen(String message);
}
```

Now, implement your `MainActivity` like the following using the interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DownloadListener {

    EditText cityName;
    TextView resultTextView;

    public void findWeather(View view) {

        Log.i("cityName", cityName.getText().toString());

        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cityName.getWindowToken(), 0);

        try {
            String encodedCityName =
                    URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
            task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName + "&apiid=5e8119137ab2c795f32cbbc4b046c57f");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cityName = findViewById(R.id.cityNameEditText);
        resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListen(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        DownloadListener listener;

        public DownloadTask(DownloadListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    System.out.print("while loop");
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = null;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                String message = "";
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

                Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String main = "";
                    String description = "";

                    main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                    description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                    if (main != "" && description != "") {
                        message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";
                    }
                }

                if (message != "") {
                    resultTextView.setText(message);
                } else {
                    listener.httpResponseReceiver("Could not find weather");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                listener.httpResponseReceiver("Could not find weather");
            }
        }
    }
}
```